# API requests for customers/ other info always returns with error 404

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, http-error-404

I have established and confirmed the roles/attributes on the admin side and have been successful in getting the permanent tokens for the site, but have been unable to make any calls to the Magento API as it always returns with error 404.

Here are a few of the links I have used on POSTMAN:
https://webstore1.tcacoustic.com.sg/api/rest/customers
https://webstore1.tcacoustic.com.sg/api/rest/products

Version: Magento CE 1.9.3.3 on IIS

Hope someone can help me on this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your api url rewrite might be a case. Please try the below URL in your browser as it's a direct call to your api.php

> https://webstore1.tcacoustic.com.sg/api.php?type=rest

It's producing expected result for the API endpoint.

In your .htacess this part is handling the URL rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

First check this line is commented or not in .htaccess. Also check your IIS configuration.

Comment: I am getting another error after using the above recommended URL:
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":404,"message":"Request does not match type route."}]}}

Will look through the .htaccess and Web.config. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: After editing the Web.config, the API calls are returning a different error -

"Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getRole() on null in"
"app\code\community\MagentoHackathon\AdvancedAcl\Helper\Data.php"

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9.2.3, i try to get products list using REST API oAuth ver 1.0, so that i am using postman or Try with URL, both getting error. Workout : I have create consumer and have consumer key, consumer token as well as getting Token Key and Token Secret. I did everything still ia m getting 404 error in postman or url, can you help me? @Rinto George

Comment: @Gem, I know its been long long long time, but I wonder if you're able to solve the 404 error you were getting?